Why does git checkout -f not revert my modified changes?
I always use git checkout -f to revert changes to the last commit and never had any problems. Rarely though do I get into this weird state where it doesn't work and I have no idea what is going on.

When I do a git diff this is the result, there is a change in the permissions but why should I not be able to revert permissions?

This state probably happened after I moved the trace-pro folder to another location using mv command.

Are you using any cloud sync services on your user directory? I have noticed problems like this with OneDrive, for example. OneDrive does not appear to store Unix file permissions, so, the permissions always are somewhat random.

Hi @JörgWMittag thank you for your response. No I'm not using these services. Also I did have this problem once a few years ago on a pure Linux Ubuntu environment.

Why not use more modern and suitable git restore? Did you check if that works correctly in this case?
